# Htaccess redirect issue with query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URL `domain.com/index.php`

I have written this code to redirect to `clientarea.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php /clientarea.php [R=301]
```

Now this works **except** for urls that contain a query string (eg. `domain.com/index.php?=something`). This will also redirect but I don't want it when there is a query string.

Can anyone tell me how I can do it ?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything about `&` in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent rewriting when a query string is there

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /clientarea.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You're welcome, let me update your question to make it clear since some people seem to have a hard time understanding exactly what you meant

Comment: See this is done bt why my URLS are replace with clientarea.php, I dont want them instead it should remain same index.php

Comment: If you still want to see `index.php` then you need to remove `R=301` flag since you asked it to **redirect**. Otherwise, it is called a (internal) rewrite

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /clientarea.php? [R=301]
```

$ marks the end of the string in the regex.

Comment: no it is not working my url are ending with
index.php?m=smd&action=wizard